# get generic type restful response

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, jersey

EDITED

I'm having troubles consuming a restful webservice from a java EE web application using Jersey. I have a restful web service (for testing purposes) and I have to use the response to show it. The problem is that I'm getting a ElementNSImpl object on the field that uses a generic type. What am I doing wrong? Thank you so much.

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces("application/json; charset=utf-8")
public ResultadoConsulta consultar(LiquidacionProvisoriaEntradaServicio parametro){

    ResultadoConsulta<ResultadoLiquidacionDetalleRespuestaServicio> resultado = new ResultadoConsulta<>();
    List<ResultadoLiquidacionDetalleRespuestaServicio> lista = new ArrayList<>();
    ResultadoLiquidacionDetalleRespuestaServicio r = new ResultadoLiquidacionDetalleRespuestaServicio();
    r.setCodigoConcepto(1);
    r.setCodigoFormaPago("formapago");
    r.setDescripcionConcepto1("descripcion 1");
    r.setDescripcionConcepto2("descripcion 2");
    r.setDescripcionEmpresaFacturadora("empresa facturadora");
    r.setFechaComprobante(new Date());
    r.setFechaGeneracionConcepto(new Date());
    r.setIdEmpresaFactura(1);
    r.setImporteConcepto(2F);
    r.setNumeroCuenta(1234);
    r.setNumeroCuentaFactura(12343);
    r.setNumeroFormaPago(Short.valueOf("2"));


    lista.add(r);

    resultado.setListaResultado(lista);
    resultado.setCantidadRegistrosTotales(200);
    resultado.setNumeroPagina(1);
    resultado.setTamanoPagina(1);

    return resultado;


}
```

And the method from my client:

```
public <T> T ejecutarWebServiceJsonPost(Object requestEntity, Class<T> responseType) throws ClientErrorException {
    return webTarget.request(javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).post(javax.ws.rs.client.Entity.entity(requestEntity, javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON), responseType);
}
```

Response classes:

```
 @XmlRootElement
public class ResultadoConsulta<T> {
    @XmlElement
    private List<T> listaResultado;
    @XmlElement
    private Integer cantidadRegistrosTotales;
    @XmlElement
    private Integer numeroPagina;
    @XmlElement
    private Integer tamanoPagina;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For a generic response, you can try this:

```
    import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces("application/json; charset=utf-8")
    public Response consultar(LiquidacionProvisoriaEntradaServicio parametro){

        .....

        return Response.status(200).entity(resultado).build();
    }
```

Source: [Jersey Hello World Example](https://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/jersey-hello-world-example/)

Comment: Hi Carlos, thanks for your answer. I have already tried that and didn't work for me...

Comment: How way you try to get the response in your client?

Comment: This is the method from my client...


 `public <T> T ejecutarWebServiceJsonPost(Object requestEntity, Class<T> responseType) throws ClientErrorException {
    return webTarget.request(javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).post(javax.ws.rs.client.Entity.entity(requestEntity, javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON), responseType);
}`

Comment: And then...

`resultado = cliente.ejecutarWebServiceJsonPost(parametro, ResultadoConsulta.class);`